# Java: PriorityQueue - Grocery Store Simulation

Tags: java, queue, simulation, priority-queue

*I've been working away at this problem for the past 10-12 hours*, and was 
wondering if you guys could help me debug/point me in the right general direction. **The object of the program is to simulate a grocery store queue-line**, which I'm attempting to accomplish using:

- PriorityQueue (FIFO) data structure
- System.nanoTime() - *to keep track of elapsed time*
- SimpleDateFormat - *to keep track of when customers enter queue (timestamp)*

---

I've consulted with colleagues, on-campus tutoring services, professors and the given course textbook: "Java How To Program: Deitel & Deitel" to no avail.

The provided pseudocode for the problem is as follows (*I'm not trying to get you to do it for me*):

> > Run the supermarket simulation for a 12-hour day (720 minutes), using the following algorithm:
>
> ---
>
> 1. Choose a random integer between 1 and 4 to determine the mintue at which first customer arrives
> 2. At first customer's arrival time, do the following:
>
>    - Determine the customer's service time (random integer 1 to 4)
> 3. Begin servicing the customer
>
>    - Schedule arrival time of next customer (random integer 1 to 4 added to current time)
> 4. For each minute of the day, consider the following:
>
>    - If the next customer arrives, proceed as follows:
>    - Say so.
>    - Enqueue the customer.
>    - Schedule the arrival time of the next customer.
>    - If the service was completed for the last customer, do the following:
>
>      - Say so.
>      - Dequeue the next customer to be serviced
>      - Determine the customer's service completion time (random integer from 1 to 4 added to the current time)

**The issues I'm experiencing:**

1. **Attempts to 'delay' program as customers arrive/are serviced are ineffective** (perhaps System.nanoTime() miscalculations? *(I've double checked all calculations, may still be wrong)* - see: *newCustomer(), serveCustomer()*
2. 84983 customers at the end of 1 minute, illogical since delays of 1-4 minutes between customer arrivals (timing issue)
3. **Queue never increases in size**, customers are added, then removed linearly (*wrong*)

**Note**

- *I have reduced the simulation time to 1 minute for testing purposes*
- *I cannot use a multithreaded approach to solve this problem, must be done using FIFO on single thread*
- **Customers arrive at intervals of 1 to 4 SECONDS, reduced for testing purposes**

Here is my code:

```
package grocerystoresimulation;
/*
* @import
*/
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
/*
* @author: Tyler J Fisher
* Date: 2/27/2012
*/
public class GroceryStoreSimulation {

/*
* @fields 
*/
private PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
private Random rand = new Random(); //instantiate new Random object    

private Date date = new Date();
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd - hh:mm:ss a"); 
private ArrayList<String> timeStamp = new ArrayList<String>(); //store timestamps

private int totalCustomers; //# of customers served during simulation

private long startTime = System.nanoTime(); //time of initial build
private long simulationTime = 1; //desired time in minutes
private long firstWaitTime = generateWaitTime(); 
private long serviceCustomerAt;

/*
* @constuctor
*/
public GroceryStoreSimulation(){
    System.out.println("Instantiated new GroceryStoreSimulation @ ["
            + dateFormat.format(date) + "]\n" + insertDivider());
} //GroceryStoreSimulation()

public void run(){
    //Main program body
    try {
        Thread.sleep(firstWaitTime); //generate wait time for first customer
        System.out.println("Delay until first customer: " + firstWaitTime);
        newCustomer(totalCustomers);
        serveCustomer();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){/*Catch 'em all*/}

    while((System.nanoTime()-startTime)<=(simulationTime*60000000000L)-firstWaitTime){
        try {
            newCustomer(totalCustomers); //enque customer 
            serveCustomer();
        } catch(Exception e){/*Catch 'em all*/}
    }
    System.out.println("Exit");
    System.exit(0); //stop runtime
} //run()

/*
* @return String
*/ 
@Override 
public String toString(){
    return this.pq.toString();
} //toString()

private void serveCustomer(){
    long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;
    while((elapsedTime)<(serviceCustomerAt)){ 
        elapsedTime += System.nanoTime()/10000000;
    }
    if(pq.size()!=0){
        System.out.println("Dequeued customer @[" + dateFormat.format(new Date())
                + "]");
        pq.poll(); //remove first element of queue
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Queue is empty!");
    }
} //serveCustomer()

/*
* @param String ID
*/ 
private void newCustomer(int ID){
    long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;
    long waitTime = (long)generateWaitTime()*1000000;
    long generateAt = elapsedTime+waitTime;

    while((elapsedTime)<(generateAt)){/*Wait*/    
        elapsedTime += System.nanoTime()/10000000; //increment elapsed time
    }      
    serviceCustomerAt = 0; //reset service wait time value
    System.out.println("Customer # " + totalCustomers + " added to queue. . .");
    totalCustomers++;
    pq.offer(ID); //insert element into PriorityQueue
    System.out.println("Queue size: " + pq.size()); //output linesize
    assignTimestamp(ID); //call assignArrivalTime() method

    //Calculate time until customer served
    waitTime = (long)generateWaitTime()*1000000;
    elapsedTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;

    serviceCustomerAt = elapsedTime + waitTime;
    System.out.println("Service delay: " + waitTime/1000000);
} //newCustomer()

/*
* @param String ID 
*/
private void assignTimestamp(int ID){
    timeStamp.add(ID + ": " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    System.out.println(timeStamp.get(totalCustomers-1));
} //assignArrivalTime()

* @return int 
*/
private int generateWaitTime(){
    //Local variables
    int Low = 1000;  //1000ms
    int High = 4000; //4000ms
    return rand.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
}//generateWaitTime()

/*
* @return String
*/
private static String insertDivider(){
    return ("****");
}//insertDivider()
```

output:

> run:
>   Instantiated new GroceryStoreSimulation @ [2012/03/13 - 01:55:23 AM]
>
> ---
>
> Delay until first customer: 1263
>   Customer # 0 added to queue. . .
>   Queue size: 1
>   0: 2012/03/13 - 01:55:24 AM
>   Service delay: 1373
>   Dequeued customer @[2012/03/13 - 01:55:24 AM]
>   Customer # 1 added to queue. . .
>   Queue size: 1
>   1: 2012/03/13 - 01:55:24 AM
>   Service delay: 2188
>   Dequeued customer @[2012/03/13 - 01:55:24 AM]
>   Customer # 2 added to queue. .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   Service delay: 3379
>   Dequeued customer @[2012/03/13 - 01:55:24 AM]
>   Customer # 927 added to queue. . .
>   Queue size: 1
>   927: 2012/03/13 - 01:55:24 AM
>   Service delay: 2300
>   Service delay: 2300BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: You can't put a code block immediately after a numbered list.  Its been a subject of contention on [meta] that this hasn't been fixed.  Not sure if it will.  Anyhow, please remember that in future.  Also, next time, you might want to avoid the 80-column wide `/********` dividers and go with the minimum required number of asterisks.  Please check my [edit] to see what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
   while((elapsedTime)<(generateAt)){/*Wait*/    
       elapsedTime += System.nanoTime()/10000000; //increment elapsed time
   }
```

to

```
   while((elapsedTime)<(generateAt)){/*Wait*/    
       elapsedTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime; //update elapsed time
   }
```

NOTE: I believe you should re-work your two methods to not do any waiting, but rather simply check if it is time to queue/de-queue a customer.  In the main while loop, you can add a Thread.sleep(1000) so that every 1 second, you call each method which checks if it's time to queue/de-queue a customer.  Upon successfully doing so, update the time at which the next person should be serviced/generated.

Comment: Thank you! Now there is a delay between queuing/enqueuing the customers. I've been trying to do that for hours.

Comment: Yes I believe there are still some other errors... I'm not sure why but your newCustomer method seems to be resetting the serviceCustomer timer?  That seems incorrect to me, but hopefully this answer has provided you with some insight as to where the remaining issue might be.

Comment: Ah, it's unnecessary now that I look over it. It shouldn't be causing any issues though, it isn't called until a new value is assigned. From what I can tell, after removing there has been no effect on runtime.

Answer (score 4):

A couple things to think about:

You're *simulating* a 12-hour day, at 1 minute resolution, there is no need to have your program actually *running* for any specific amount of time (ie there is no need for `Thread.sleep()` at any point).

You do want a FIFO queue, a `PriorityQueue` is, by definition, not a FIFO queue. (I haven't checked if it actually makes a difference in your case, but you should probably be aware of the difference).

Doing things like this:

```
try {
  newCustomer(totalCustomers); //enque customer
  serveCustomer();
} catch(Exception e){/*Catch 'em all*/}
```

Will cause nothing but frustration and hair pulling.

#### Edit

Unless there's a specific requirement to use `sleep()` to time your code (wasn't clear, but I'm assuming there isn't), something like this would be a lot easier:

```
for(int minute = 0; minute < 720; minute++){
  // process customer arrival and service
}
```

Hopefully that can give you some ideas.

Comment: Do you have any alternative suggestions? I really don't know where to go from here, I've exhausted all options known to me. I have no idea what I'm doing here...

Comment: He's got great point.  You're using a while loop to effectively sleep the thread... you might as well add Thread.sleep in your while loop (who cares if you wait several thousand nanoseconds if your times will be in between 1 and 4 minutes)

Comment: When I tried that, the simulation would run out of bounds (i.e longer than designated time). I was hoping to avoid thread.sleep for this reason.

Comment: @Dmitri, it would be a lot easier (maybe), but...it would require that I completely rewrite my code from scratch since that implementation wouldn't require a timer, would it? I only use Thread.sleep() for the arrival of the FIRST customer. Seemed like the most straightforward approach

Comment: @Tyler: it's a rewrite, but it's about 1/5 the code - you don't need timers or queues, just the for loop and two counters.  Entirely up to you, of course.

Comment: @Dmitri, I'll keep it in mind, thank you! Going to keep at it for the rest of the night. Have to make at least some ground on this.